# Warum wird "ausreichend" nicht dekliniert?

Tags: grammaticality, adjective-ending, declension

Wir betrachten die folgenden Sätze:

> Es sollte auf ausreichend Bewegung bei der Arbeit geachtet werden.
>
> Außerdem brauchen wir ausreichend Flüssigkeit für das Gehirn.
>
> Es is kein ausreichend langer Schlaf möglich.
>
> Streifen, der sich bei ausreichend kalter und feuchter Luft bildet.

> Die genannte Eigenschaft ist in ausreichendem Maße vorhanden.
>
> regelmäßige und ausreichende Versorgung eines Organs mit Nährstoffen
>
> ein Land ohne ausreichende Verkehrswege.

Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausreichend) und Langenscheidt ist *ausreichend* das Partizip Präsens von ausreichen, das als Adjektiv verwendet wird. Warum wird es in manchen Sätzen dekliniert und in manchen nicht?

Comment: **Eine auf Deutsch gestellte Frage ist kein Duplikat einer auf Englisch gestellten Frage.** Zwar wurde das schon mehrfach erwähnt, aber offenbar muss das immer und immer wieder erwähnt werden. Ich votiere natürlich für die Wiedereröffnung!

Answer (score 3):

In diesem Sinne ist *ausreichend* ein Adverb, kein Adjektiv und bedeutet "genug".
Es ist ausreichend (genug) Essen für alle da. Du solltest ausreichend Wasser trinken.

ausreichend (Adj.) in ausreichender Menge

Comment: Und was ist die Bedeutung von "ausreichend" in den letzten drei Beispielen? Heißt es nicht auch genug? Oben haben wir z.B. *ausreichend* Flüssigkeit und unten *ausreichende* Versorgung. Die heißen genug Flüssigkeit für Gehirn und genug Nährstoffversorgung für ein Organ. Eins ist dekliniert und das andere nicht.

Comment: Es ist kein ausreichend langer Schlaf möglich.

Streifen, der sich bei ausreichend kalter und feuchter Luft bildet.

Comment: Es ist kein ausreichend langer Schlaf möglich.

Streifen, der sich bei ausreichend kalter und feuchter Luft bildet. In diesen Beispielen sieht man klar, dass es um ein Adverb geht, das Adjektiv näher bestimmt.

Comment: Es sollte auf ausreichend Bewegung bei der Arbeit geachtet werden.

Außerdem brauchen wir ausreichend Flüssigkeit für das Gehirn. In diesen Sätzen können wir ausreichend durch mehr ersetzen, was grammatisch korrekt ist. "Mehr" ist Adverb. In den letzten drei Beispielen  sind nur Substantive (Nomengruppe), keine Verben, also es muss dann "ausreichend"  dekliniert werden. Das Verb "sein" ist ein Kopulaverb, kein Vollverb.

Comment: Die genannte Eigenschaft ist in ausreichendem Maße vorhanden.

regelmäßige und ausreichende Versorgung eines Organs mit Nährstoffen

ein Land ohne ausreichende Verkehrswege. Das sind die letzten Beispiele, die ich gemeint habe. Hier sind nur Substantivgruppen.

Comment: Kurz gesagt: In den ersten zwei Sätzen haben wir ein Adverb der Art und Weise. Diese Adverbien lassen sich durch die Frage "wie viel?" erkennen, z.B. wie viel?- genug, kaum, ausreichend In den dritten und vierten Beispielen bestimmen die Adverbien "ausreichend" die Adjektive.In den letzen drei Beispielen haben wir reine  Nomengruppen, wo "ausreichend" nur Ajektiv sein kann.